# Find P(A and B) given P(A) and P(B)

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

Say P(A) is 0.4 and P(B) is 0.1 and P(neither) is .7

How would I calculate the probability of P(A and B)?
I have looked at conditional probability examples and cannot find one where only P(A) and P(B) is given.

Comment: You can look for Venn Diagrams. See for example http://www.purplemath.com/modules/venndiag2.htm. You need to find area of the region 1, while you know the area of 1+2, 1+3, 4 and 1+2+3+4

Comment: I understand when the sets given are say {1,2,3} and {3,4,5}. What do I do when i'm given only the probability(like above)?

Comment: Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=probability%20self-study%20and%20venn.  If that doesn't work, remove "Venn" from the search: you will find several thousand relevant posts to help you.